# I once stole something but I don't know who it belonged to so how do I seek forgiveness for it?

Tags: forgiveness, theft

I once stole a piece of clothing in the hostel. I don't know who did it belong to. I don't know the owner. It's been years now. I have realized my sin and have repented to God. Cried and promised never to do such thing again. But since it's transgression against another human being so how do I fix it? I don't know the person. And there's no way I can find them. Is there anyway to compensate for it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/43017

Answer (score 1):

In Islam or in any other religion or from good manners perspective the solution is first to ask Almighty Allah for Forgiveness, second try not to do it again, last but not least, make a charity with the approximate price or value of the thing you took and whish this good fact to the person who owns what you took from him/her.
تصدق بقيمة المأخوذ و انوي ذلك صدقة لصاحب أو صاحبة المأخوذ.
This advice is for me, for you, for everyone. Everyone is the one at fault but the good one is who keeps asking Allah for forgiveness and trying again and again and infinitely to avoid doing bad things. That's the real point. stay safe